# result is 0.00 when attempting to get minimum value in array

Tags: java, arrays

In eclipse when when i run this code the minTemp result is always 0.00 although maxTemp and the average results are fine. Cant seem to fix it. Any suggestions?

```
package exercises;

public class PracticalAnswer2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double[] temps;
      temps = new double[7];
      double total = 0.0;
      double maxTemp = 0.0;
      double minTemp = 0.0;

      temps[0]= 3.4;
      temps[1]= 4.2;
      temps[2]= 9.0;
      temps[3]= 2.2;
      temps[4]= 4.5;
      temps[5]= 6.4;
      temps[6]= 3.1;

      for(int loop = 0; loop<temps.length;loop++) {
         total+=temps[loop];

         if(temps[loop]<minTemp) {
            minTemp = temps[loop];
         }

         if(temps[loop]>maxTemp) {
            maxTemp = temps[loop];
         }

      }

      System.out.printf(" average temperature : %.2f \n",(total/temps.length) );
      System.out.printf("minimum temerature : %.2f \n", minTemp);
      System.out.printf("maximum temperature: %.2f \n", maxTemp);
   }
}
```

Comment: You initialize `minTemp` to `0.0`. Nothing in the array is less than that. Try setting it to a large value, like `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Well, it's starting at 0.0, it likely never gets a temp higher than this, so why are you surprised that you're getting 0.0? Have you thought of starting at a higher value? `Double.MAX_VALUE` perhaps?

Comment: all working now. Great.

Comment: Voting to close as a trivial issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because temps[loop] is never lower than 0. Try having something way high for the mintemp. Something like `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Or set it to temp[0] assuming the array has some non-zero number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(temps[loop] < minTemp) {  // minTemp initialized with 0.0
        minTemp = temps[loop];
  }

  temps[0]= 3.4;
  temps[1]= 4.2;
  temps[2]= 9.0;
  temps[3]= 2.2;
  temps[4]= 4.5;
  temps[5]= 6.4;
  temps[6]= 3.1;
```

None values in array temps is smaller than 0.0, Your code does what it intends to do.
Usually, when we use minXXX or maxXXX, we initialize minXXX with a very large number and maxXXX with a small number. When iterating the iterables, it compares the values and assign the desired min/max value

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `minTemp` and `maxTemp` with 0.0. With the loops you wrote you will never be able to change those values, cause any of values from `temps[]` is less than 0.0. I think that in the first loop, you should assign `temps[0]` to `minTemp` and to `maxTemp`, and then in next loops check if next values from `temps[]` are lower than `minTemp` and higher than `maxTemp`. If this occurs, then you should assign this new value to `minTemp` or `maxTemp`. By the way `maxTemp` looks to be ok in your project.

Another possibility to make your `minTemp` value loop work as you expected is to initialize it with `Double.MAX_VALUE`rather than with 0.0.